# Where the posts image will be stored in the database wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to know where the posts images are stored in the database.I want to fetch the image url of respective posts.I have searched in wp_posts table but i couldn't find it..Can anyone help me out.

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly you want to do or achieve ? I am sure there is an easier way than fiddling with the DB ...

Comment: @ObmerkKronen... On clicking on any post modal should be displayed with the respective post image and content... I am able to fetch the content,title to modal but, not able to fetch image.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress stores images by default under the wp-content/uploads - directory, with current year and month as subdirectories (yyyy/mm). So far example `wp-content/uploads/2013/09/img.png` .

The images are included in their html-tags in the `blog_posts`-table, in the column `post_content`.

Comment: @K Maertens..Where the image URL's are stored in the database

Comment: The images are included in their html-tags in the blog_posts-table, in the column post_content.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to display post attachements in your page view, that's a way to do it with WordPress' own functions. Will get all post attachements and list them at thumbnails size.

```
<?php    
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$attachements = get_posts( $args );

if ( $attachements ):
?>

<!-- List all post images -->
<ul>         
<?php
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
       echo '<li>';
       echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
       echo '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>

<?php
endif;
?>
```

However, if merely want to know in which column is stored the attachement URL, the answer is `wp_posts > guid`

Answer (score 1):

Always try to use the functions provided by WordPress to fulfill the requirements. Yes, the images( image urls ) are stored inside wp_posts table as attachments.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1, 
    'post_status' => null, 
    'post_parent' => $post->ID 
); 
$attached_images = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

Comment: Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_all_attachments